# Using space as delimiter and print the text on CMD prompt in Windows batch

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, delimiter

I have the below piece of line placed in a note pad.
I want to use “space ” as the delimiter and print the word in list basis using Windows batch programming .
I have already written the code for reading the note pad and displaying the output on the command prompt.
How I will write the code for using space as a delimiter and display the output in a  list on command prompt.

For ex.

```
[Sun Mar 7 23:30:23 2004] [info] [client 64.242.88.10] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed
```

This is my context in notepad.
My intent is to use space as delimiter starting from (104)connection to the end of the line and display it as list.

So the output on the command console should be like:

```
(104)Connection
Reset
By
peer:
client
stopped
connection
before
send
body
completed
```

Comment: You don't actually want DOS, right? You want something that can be run from the Windows command line? Please tell me you're not using actual DOS in 2016.

Comment: i am using DOS programming.i have written the code in DOS and this is a part of the program.

Comment: DOS 6.22 or batch? There is a HUGE difference.

Comment: set /P search_string= Enter the string you would like to search for:
find "%search_string%" C:\ServiceLog%_store%.txt


this is for finding a text in the note pad .then after finding i want to use space as delimiter and devide the output.

Comment: this is in DOS batch file.(.bat) extension

Comment: I'm sorry, but you still haven't answered my question. Are you using the DOS operating system, or is this running on Windows? This can't be done in DOS, but it can be done very easily in Windows.

Comment: i am doing on windows.My system is running on windows.

Comment: Windows console program `cmd.exe` has nothing whatsoever to do with DOS.

Answer (score 1):

This solution starts when you have the required line in a *text file* called `theLine.txt`. I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean with "I have the line placed in a note pad". You may generate this file by just redirecting your output from the "command prompt" (that is, the screen) into the file. For example:

```
find "%search_string%" C:\log%_store%.txt > theLine.txt
```

This is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal


rem Create here "theLine.txt" input file with the required line


rem Read the line from the input file
set /P "line=" < theLine.txt

rem Separate the line in words at spaces and show they
set "wordFound="
for %%a in ("%line: =" "%") do (
   if %%a equ "(104)Connection" set "wordFound=true"
   if defined wordFound echo %%~a
)
```

This is the output shown in the command console by this solution:

```
(104)Connection
reset
by
peer:
client
stopped
connection
before
send
body
completed
```

Comment: Aftre finding the text from the notepad , output line is getting displayed but it is not delimited with spaces.

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow you... Do you want that each word preserve the space after it? If so, insert a space before the second quote in `for` and first `if` commands, that is: `for %%a in ("%line: = " "%") do (` and `if %%a equ "(104)Connection " set "wordFound=true"`

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35150865.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO CALL :process %%a

GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "prefix="
goTO loope

:loop
SHIFT
:loope
SET "word=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED word GOTO :eof
:ops
IF "%prefix%"=="f" ECHO(%~1&GOTO loop
IF "%word:~0,1%"=="[" SET "prefix=s"
IF "%word:~-1%"=="]" SET "prefix=e"&GOTO loop
IF "%prefix%"=="s" GOTO loop
IF "%prefix%"=="e" SET "prefix=f"&GOTO ops
GOTO loop
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35150865.txt` containing your data for my testing.

This process simply applies each line from the source file to a subroutine, so the line appears to be a series of parameters.

The subroutine processes the line; first initialising `prefix` acts as a flag to specify whether or not we are in the `prefix` seof a line (ie up to the last `]`)

If the word found starts `[` then `prefix` is set to `s` (start of unwanted line-prefix)

If the word found ends `]` then `prefix` is set to `e` (potential end of unwanted line-prefix) and the next word is processed.

If we still have `s` in `prefix` then we need to continue until we get `e` so get next word.

If we have a word that neither starts nor ends with a bracket and we've got to the end of the prefix, then set `prefix` to `f` (we've finished with the prefix.) and we need to output the current word.

---

Here's another approach:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35150865.txt"
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO CALL :process1 %%a

GOTO :EOF

:process1
SET "word=%*"
:process1a
SET "short=%word:*]=%"
IF "%short%" neq "%word%" SET "word=%short%"&GOTO process1a
CALL :process2 %short%
GOTO :eof

:process2
SET "word=%~1"
IF DEFINED word ECHO(%~1&shift&GOTO process2
GOTO :eof
```

Comment: Its not working for me. BDW what is sourcedir ?
and where is the space delimiter being used

Comment: `sourcedir` is the directory in which the source file resides. I use this so that people who want to use spaces in file/directory names don't need to ask questions. As I say, you'd need to set `sourcedir` to suit your setup. As I've set it, it suits my system. The space-delimiter is being virtualised. When a string including spaces (strictly separators) is passed as a parameter using `call` then the subroutine sees the string as a series of parameters. The `shift` command shuufles the parameters along one position after the processing of each individual parameter is complete.

Comment: "It's not working for me" sadly doesn't provide enough information to analyse the problem.

Comment: `set /P search_string= Enter the text:
find "%search_string%" C:\log%_store%.txt 
if exist C:\SignServiceLog%_store%.txt goto print

echo.
echo. Path not found
echo.a) The network is down or you don't have the required permissions.
echo.
echo.Please check and try again.
Pause
goto Start

:print

echo.
echo. Done!!!!!
Pause`

This is the code for searching a text from the text placed in the C drive.
It fetches a output line and display on the command if the text is present in the notepad.you can refer the same line in question section.Then how i will break it from here?